# Facebook website login API doesn't work

Tags: facebook, api, dns

We had a fully working website Facebook login API on our test site, and after we moved to a new domain, it stopped working. Of course we created a new app for the new domain, but still i get a error message:

```
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /data/www/kuponia.hu/docs/system/includes/library.inc.php on line 9  
Notice: Undefined index: PHP_AUTH_USER in /data/www/kuponia.hu/docs/system/includes/mainPLUS.php on line 52
Notice: Undefined index: mobile_access in /data/www/kuponia.hu/docs/system/includes/config.php on line 63
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /data/www/kuponia.hu/docs/system/includes/fns.php on line 10
Notice: Undefined index: userid in /data/www/kuponia.hu/docs/system/includes/fns.php on line 11
Notice: Undefined index: fb_access_token in /data/www/kuponia.hu/docs/system/modules/facebook/facebook.php on line 6
Notice: Undefined index: userid in /data/www/kuponia.hu/docs/system/modules/facebook/facebook.php on line 37
```

Any idea what is wrong? The new API key is working with the old site (of course with a domain change) flawlessly, but if i try with the new domain, still doesn't work. We need this Facebook connect login API very urgently.Ideas please! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a little on the web I've found this:
http://www.ajaykumarsingh.com/php/notice-a-session-had-already-been-started-ignoring-session_start-in-on-line.html 
and this (actually telling you the same as the first):
https://dmadan.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/notice-a-session-had-already-been-started-ignoring-session_start/
Hope it'll help you.

Summary:

> This problem occurs when your PHP.INI file has session.autostart
>   turned on. You’ll need to turn this off by editing your PHP.INI file and setting it to off and / or placing a `.htaccess` file in the root of your web directory with the following value: `php_flag session.auto_start 0` and using `if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();` in your code instead of `session_start();` .

Just noticed that there are also a lot of similar question on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=A+session+had+already+been+started+-+ignoring+session_start%28%29